# save variable with different name for each loop

Tags: python, pandas

I am using a function to calculate some statistical values for a time-series. Right now, I am trying to save these variables with different names for each run of the function:

My Code basically looks like this:

```py
name = 'location_A'
Daten = pd.Dataframe

def Validation(Daten, name):
    Data_A = Daten['location_A']
    Data_B = Daten['reference_Data']

    pearson = Data_A.corr(Data_B)

    pearson_+'name' = pearson
Validation(name, Daten)
```

So I am trying to save the pearson coefficient of location A as pearson_location_A. In the next run I will do the same for location B and so on, but I want the values to be saved seperately.

I tried with ne approach above (name+'location_A') but it didnt really work out.

Can somebody help me out?

Comment: Have a look at this: https://www.codespeedy.com/convert-string-into-variable-name-in-python/. Another way would be to use a dictionary and have keys instead of separate variables

Comment: A good way to do this is to save the variables as a dictionary, changing the key every iteration

Answer (score 0):

```
np.random.seed(0)
for name in ['location_A', 'location_B']:
    globals()[f'pearson_{name}'] = np.random.randint(100)

pearson_location_A
#44
pearson_location_B
#47
```

Or, if you don't want to pollute your `globals` dictionary:

```
pearson = {}
for name in ['location_A', 'location_B']:
    pearson[name] = np.random.randint(100)
pearson
#{'location_A': 44, 'location_B': 47}
```